# Install Stored Procedure on Multiple Databases

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Is there any way to easily create a stored procedure on multiple MySQL databases at once? All the databases are on the same MySQL install.

Comment: When you say "multiple databases", do you mean "multiple schemas"?  You can install a single stored procedure in any schema and leverage it from others, assuming privileges have not been revoked for that user on that schema.

Comment: I save my common procedures in mysql schema and use it using ## call mysql.some_sp();

Comment: It might be worth investigating using replication, of stored procedures only, if that's even possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend doing a copy-paste and create the stored procedure in each database schema if they need to be available to that schema only.  Otherwise I would follow the recommendation from 'Kelly Vista' and just refer to the stored procedure located in one of the schema's.

Answer (score 2):

**Installing in all schemas**

To get a list of the schemas, use `show databases;`. Combine this with `-- use`:

```
use schemaA;
-- use schemaB;
-- use schemaC;

create procedure ...
```

Manually iterate through the schemas, removing and uncommenting `use` clauses as you move on, checking that everything works out. In MySQL Workbench, Ctrl+Shift+Enter is your friend.

**Installing routines in a subset of schemas**

Normally you don't want to install the stored routine in *all* schemas on a server, but only in a *subset* --- often defined by the set of schemas which already have some specific stored routine installed. Then, [as discussed on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3466728/mysql-stored-procedure-query-to-check-if-exists-or-not), you can use a query like this to get the names of the relevant schemas:

```
SELECT ROUTINE_SCHEMA FROM `information_schema`.`ROUTINES` where specific_name = 'MyRoutine';
```

**Verification**

After deploying routines, to verify the existence of them, you can use a query like this:

```
SELECT distinct
    r1.ROUTINE_SCHEMA, 
    case when r2.specific_name is not null then '' else '####' end as RoutineName1,
    case when r3.specific_name is not null then '' else '####' end as RoutineName2,
    case when r4.specific_name is not null then '' else '####' end as RoutineName3
FROM 
    `information_schema`.`ROUTINES` as r1 
LEFT JOIN (select * from `information_schema`.`ROUTINES` where specific_name = 'RoutineName1') as r2 on r1.routine_schema = r2.routine_schema
LEFT JOIN (select * from `information_schema`.`ROUTINES` where specific_name = 'RoutineName2') as r3 on r1.routine_schema = r3.routine_schema
LEFT JOIN (select * from `information_schema`.`ROUTINES` where specific_name = 'RoutineName3') as r4 on r1.routine_schema = r4.routine_schema
where 
    r1.specific_name = 'FilteringRoutineName';
```

This query will check whether `RoutineName1`, `RoutineName2` and `RoutineName3` exist in the database schemas on your server which have the routine `FilteringRoutineName`. If a routine is missing, it will be marked with `####`.

Of course, this only checks for routine existence. To verify their implementation, you may need a database diff tool (such as MySQL Compare or similar).

Comment: I've tried to automate this but it seems impossible as iterative loops cannot be used outside stored routines in MySQL, and `CREATE PROCEDURE` statements cannot be used within stored routines.

Comment: It might be possible to solve this problem using [prepared statements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13817968/iterate-mysql-schemas) executed with `EXECUTE`. I'll explore this later and update my answer to reflect any new findings.

Comment: Unfortunately, if you try to use `CREATE PROCEDURE` within a prepared statement you get _Error Code: 1295. This command is not supported in the prepared statement protocol yet_. According to a [SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5981396/can-mysql-triggers-be-created-with-dynamic-sql-from-within-a-stored-procedure), the Lua scripting language may be of use.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using Linux, a simple BASH loop with an array of schema names will let you do this.

Save your procedure definition to a file (e.g. myproc.sql), then use the file as input to mysql in the loop. If you put your sign-in details in  ~/.my.cnf you can also avoid having to put usernames and passwords on the cmdline.

```
for i in dbname1 dbname2 dbname3; do mysql ${i} < myproc.sql; done;
```