# Iterate MySQL schemas

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

**Problem description**

I have a single-tenant MySQL database setup. That is, I have one identical schema for each client.

Now I need to run a specific query for each client. That would be easy in a multi-tenant setting (where all clients share a single schema). With my setup however, I need to iterate the schemas. *More generally, I want to access a schema whose name is given by a variable.* How can that be done?

**What I've tried**

- If I try `USE varSchemaName` (where `varSchemaName` is a `varchar`
  variable), I get the error message *ERROR 1314: USE is not allowed
  in stored procedures*.
- If I try `SELECT * FROM varSchemaName.MyTable` I get 
  *Error Code: 1146. Table 'varSchemaName.MyTable' doesn't exist*. Apparently MySQL considers `varSchemaName` to be a literal, not a
  variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to build the statement first.

```
SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT * FROM ', varSchemaName, '.MyTable');
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

You can read more about prepared statements **[here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html)**.

You might be tempted to use variables for tablenames, but that doesn't work. Those parameters are for values in where clauses and so on. The above way is the way to go.

Comment: Thanks, I just experimented with this myself and it seems to be working. If my query is long and complex, is there some better way to declare the `@sql` variable than just pasting the SQL code into the string?

Comment: I'm afraid, no, there's no better way.

Comment: I've found that with this approach, you can query a single-tenant database setup like it was multi-tenant. That's incredibly powerful and is going to solve a lot of headaches for me. Unfortunately it cannot be used to issue `CREATE` statements.

Answer (score 2):

Building on the answer from fancyPants, you can call that procedure within a loop from another procedure which queries information_schema.tables to identify the databases containing MyTable and then call fancyPants' procedure with the db names as a parameter. This method is easy if the databases have a consistent naming scheme or contain identically named objects, which sounds like the case here. The structure would be something like:

```
DELIMITER //

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS mydriver //
CREATE PROCEDURE mydriver()
BEGIN

  DECLARE varSchemaName VARCHAR(64);
  DECLARE done BOOLEAN;
  DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR
    SELECT table_schema
    FROM information_schema.tables
    WHERE table_name = 'MyTable';

  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

  OPEN cur;
    read_loop: LOOP
      FETCH cur INTO varSchemaName;
      IF done THEN
        LEAVE read_loop;
        CLOSE cur;
      END IF;

      CALL fancypants_proc(varSchemaName);

    END LOOP;
END //

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS fancypants_proc //
CREATE PROCEDURE fancypants_proc(IN varSchemaName VARCHAR(64))
BEGIN

  SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT * FROM ', varSchemaName, '.MyTable');
  PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
  EXECUTE stmt;
  DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

END //

DELIMITER ;

CALL mydriver();
```