# Deploying to hundreds of mysql databases

Tags: mysql

I work in a shop that has rolled out the same schema to many databases.  If I want to roll out the same stored procedure to say 300 databases on the same server what is the recommended method?

In something like SQL Server I could easily run the procedure in central management server, but I'm not seeing any functionality like that in MySQL.  The version I'm working with is 5.5.31.

Comment: Do any of the answers here help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4754365/install-stored-procedure-on-multiple-databases

Comment: The first question shows as answered and the answer is to do a copy and paste of the procedure manually.  That solution is not viable with a couple thousand databases.  There is a difference between saying I want to roll a procedure to a couple databases and I want to roll a procedure to a couple thousand databases.

Comment: In that case, you should have read the answer number two - the one that wasn't accepted. If an answer is accepted, that doesn't mean it's the correct one. Answer number two tells you exactly how to deploy the same procedure to X databases on the *same* server.

Comment: N.B.  Yeah it answers it if you want to manually enter each dbname.  That is not a viable option here.  Perhaps there is not a good answer, but that's what I wanted to know.